# How to differentiate regular user from admin in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing a asp.net mvc project, and i want to differentiate user session from admin session.

In my initial view i've this code to differentiate a logged in user from a non logged in user:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right !important">
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
            {
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Bem vindo à nossa loja, @Session["FirstName"]</button>

                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
                        <a>@Html.ActionLink("Editar Perfil", "Profile", "User")</a>
                    </div>
                    }

                </div>
            }

            <div>

                <a>@Html.ActionLink("E-Commerce", "ECommerce", "User")</a>
                <a>@Html.ActionLink("Agendar Visita", "Booking", "User")</a>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "User")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registo", "Registration", "User")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Entrar", "Login", "User")</li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Trying the same approach to differentiate user session from admin session, i've done this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right !important">
                    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        if (@Session["FirstName"] == "admin")
                        {
                            using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                            {
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="dropbtn">Bem vindo, admin</button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
                                    </div>
                                    }

                                </div>
                            }

                            <div>

                                <a>@Html.ActionLink("Configurar Layoyt", "ConfLayout", "Admin")</a>
                                <a>@Html.ActionLink("Adicionar Website", "AddWebsite", "Admin")</a>
                            </div>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
                            {
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <button class="dropbtn">Bem vindo à nossa loja, @Session["FirstName"]</button>

                                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Logout</a>
                                        <a>@Html.ActionLink("Editar Perfil", "Profile", "User")</a>
                                    </div>
                                    }

                                </div>
                            }

                            <div>

                                <a>@Html.ActionLink("E-Commerce", "ECommerce", "User")</a>
                                <a>@Html.ActionLink("Agendar Visita", "Booking", "User")</a>
                            </div>
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "User")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registo", "Registration", "User")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Entrar", "Login", "User")</li>
                    }
                </ul>
```

...but this didn't solve my question.

Am i using the correct approach?

Comment: You need to create roles for users. And then role provider. With doing this you will be able to use `@User.IsInRole("Admin")` .

Comment: There's no way i can do it with the attributes of my sign up form?

Comment: Try `TempData` instead of `Session`. But this is not best practice. If you have roles for users, you need to build an authorization mechanism.

Comment: I've created new project and add the roles. Thanks